# How to access @FXML components of one controller from another controller?

Tags: javafx

I am using `afterburner` to build a simple application. I have three packages package `main`, package `inwards` and package `outwards`.

`main.fxml` has an Anchor Pane in which I am loading `inwards.fxml` at application start.

Now `inwards.fxml` has a button whose action is to load `outwards.fxml` in to anchor pane of `main.fxml`.

But doing so is giving me `null pointer exception`.

Thank you.

Comment: You should not access controls of one controller inside another. Moreover, can you please add the stacktrace and the code which throws NPE?

Comment: please put some code fragments.

Comment: The whole point of afterburner is that it makes it easy to inject singleton models into the controllers (presenters). At @ItachiUchiha, you should not access the controls of one view from another view's presenter (it breaks encapsulation). Instead, interact between your presenters by accessing shared data in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, all i need to know is,  is there any way to access UI element of a controller from outside that controller. ?